# Show/hide div and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the user click on the form I am trying to show and hide a form and also trying to scroll down to see the form, the code that I have works after the first click. If i click for the first time it "shows the form but doesn't scroll down" after the first click it work fine. can someone explain me what am i doing wrong.

```
   $('#showForm').click(function()
               {
                $('.formL').toggle("slow"); 
                $('.formL').get(0).scrollIntoView()
               });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formL" style="display: none">
    <form action="">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you show html code plz ?

Comment: the user clicks on a form or on a button/link ... ?

Comment: @singebatteur I had updated the question, thank your for taking the time and trying to help

Comment: try to use the complete function of `toggle()` to scroll to it, maybe first time it cant be reached cause not visible yet (because of the duration of the fade in) https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in other answers, you are trying to scroll an element into view before it's visible and before it's reached its actual height. You can use the following approach to scroll to the amount necessary to display the form and still let the user see the animation. See comments in the code.

```js
$('#showForm').click(function() {
  var formL = $('.formL').show(), // show the form wrapper in order to get its height
      formLHeight = formL.height(),
      formLForm = formL.find('form').hide(); // hide the form itself instead
      
  formL.height(formLHeight);
  formLForm.toggle("slow", function() {
    // optionally, reset the height
    formL.height('auto');
  }); 
 
  // this line is only needed so that the code snippet will not scroll the
  // outer browser window, but only the iframe content. If you're not in an iframe,
  // you can just use the original scrollIntoView() approach instead
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = formL[0].offsetTop;
  // formL.get(0).scrollIntoView();
  
});
```

```css
#spacer {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showForm">show form</button>
<div id="spacer">some long content</div>
<div class="formL" style="display: none">
    <form action="">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet made the complete browser window (the outer StackOverflow page) scroll. I implemented a line to circumvent this, but in your environment you can probably just use your original `scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in that function you try to scroll to the form while it's still not visible. To fix this, call `scrollIntoView()` in the callback of `toggle()` function. See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ux0qt5nn/

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that on your first click, the element isn't there yet. Put the scroll function into a callback and you'll be good to go.

```
$('#showForm').click(function(){
  $('.formL').toggle("slow", function() {
    $('.formL').get(0).scrollIntoView();
  }); 
});
```

```js
$('#showForm').click(function(){
  $('.formL').toggle("slow", function() {
    $('.formL').get(0).scrollIntoView()
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttonForm" id="showForm"><span>Click here to see form</span></button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><!--Extra lines to show scroll-->

    <div class="formL" style="display: none">
      <form action="">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Of course, the user will probably not see the toggle animation at all. OP should reconsider his concept.

Comment: @Connum you are right, by doing this approach I don't see the animation

Comment: Thank you daniel, now I will try to see if i can add the animation.

Comment: So you want to scroll something into view which is not even at it's full height by that time... That's why I meant when I said you should reconsider your design concept! ;-) I have another option in mind, I'll post an answer of my own

Comment: You're welcome Pedro! I'll let @Connum take this a step further with his answer =)